# How to Use the session Store (any/redis/memcache/mongo) with socket.io & express without using cookies?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, session-cookies, session-store

I have done to configure the server & client side setup using redis session store at express+socket.io. But I have faced the problem in cookie. server & clients are in different domain(CORS) and different Server. So i cant handle the cookie. then, I need to use the session store without using cookies.

And Node App are run in multiple instances like multiple server. so, how to manage the all socket session (need to bind within a single session). I also referred connect-redis, passport , mongo modules. and also referred from "https://github.com/exratione/work-already" this link.

Thanks In Advance....

Comment: HTTP is stateless, so if you don't have a cookie, how would you differentiate the connections?

Comment: yes logan, But i can't access the cross domain cookie by using xhr-polling transport method. I have used express & socket.io with redis session store. In this case, i must need the cookie value. from foo.com(client server) to boo.com(node server).